# How to write an application for the system tray in Linux

Tags: c++, python, c, linux, system-tray

How do I write my application so it'll live in the system tray on Linux? In fact, just like [CheckGmail](http://checkgmail.sourceforge.net/).

As with CheckGmail, I'd also like some sort of popup box to appear when I hover the tray icon.

Is there an API, class or something for doing this? All I'm able to find seems to be for Windows.

If I have to be language specific, then preferably in C/C++ but a solution in Python will most likely also do.

Thanks.

Comment: linux doesn't have a system tray - your window manager might - which one are you using?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I use Xmonad with xmobar. trayer as my system tray. But I'm not sure why it's relevant to my question?

Comment: (It's not relevant, not since the freedesktop spec. (which was the whole point of having it.))

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Qt framework contains a [QSystemTrayIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html) class. This means that you can write an application in C++ or Python (or any other [language with Qt bindings](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/programming-language-support), including C#, Ada, Pascal, Perl, PHP and Ruby) and run your application on Windows, Linux, Mac or any other supported Qt operating system. I should add that Qt applications generally do a pretty good job of looking native on whatever operating system you are using without very much effort (even between Gnome/KDE on Linux). Qt also has excellent documentation, lots of sample code, a generous license and is well-maintained.

Answer (score 8):

## python-eggtrayicon

here's the example that comes with the debian package `python-eggtrayicon` in debian/testing...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk
import egg.trayicon
t = egg.trayicon.TrayIcon("MyFirstTrayIcon")
t.add(gtk.Label("Hello"))
t.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

It just shows a label in the notification area . (Search on that, and you'll probably get *much* better hits...)

Comment: Note: currently not in debian (https://packages.debian.org/python-eggtrayicon, http://packages.qa.debian.org/gnome-python-extras).

Answer (score 5):

[Qt](https://www.qt.io/product/framework) is cross platform and has support for the system tray.  Its [Python bindings](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python) are pretty good as well.  See the [example application](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QSystemTrayIcon.html) for further details.

Comment: the url provided has rotten :( please paste actual code/text from it.

Comment: I've updated the links for now. I'll try to put together a concise example later.

Answer (score 2):

From a python prompt try this.

```
import gtk

icon = gtk.StatusIcon()
icon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)

gtk.main()
```

You should see an icon in the system tray.

See this [snippet](http://eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Systray%20icon.html) for a bigger example.